# How to group data by past few weeks?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have an original table like this,

```
timestamp_ID          Country     col1      col2       col3 
2021-01-04 11:00:00     US         red       phone      car    
2021-01-04 11:00:00     US         red       sms        car   
2021-01-04 12:00:00     US         red       phone      car   
2021-01-07 11:00:00     UK         red       phone      car   
2021-01-08 11:00:00     US         red       phone      airplane   
2021-01-11 11:00:00     UK         red       sms        car   
2021-01-11 11:00:00     US         green     phone      car   
2021-01-12 11:00:00     US         red       phone      car   
2021-01-16 11:00:00     CA         red       sms        car   
2021-01-18 11:00:00     US         blue       phone     airplane   
2021-01-19 11:00:00     AU         red       phone      car    
2021-01-19 11:00:00     AU         blue       phone     train
```

Can I group my data using GROUP BY in SQL to get the aggregate value by each week?

My expected output will be like,

```
Country     col1      col2       col3   count_at_week1(2021-01-04~2021-01-10) count_at_week2  count_at_week3  ...
US         red       phone      car         2                                     0                   0
US         red       sms        car         1                                     0                   0
UK         red       phone      car         1                                     0                   0
US         red       phone      airplane    1                                     0                   0
UK         red       sms        car         0                                     1                   0
US         green     phone      car         0                                     1                   0
US         red       phone      car         0                                     1                   0
CA         red       sms        car         0                                     1                   0
US         blue       phone     airplane    0                                     0                   1
AU         red       phone      car         0                                     0                   1
AU         blue       phone     train       0                                     0                   1
```

Comment: 1) *Always* include your dbms and version # because syntax and capabilities vary by vendor 2) How are you defining "week"... start day, end day? 3) What you're describing is a PIVOT. Is the number of week columns *finite*? If not, you'll need dynamic sql. If there's a known maximum, what is that number? a 4) What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: Hi @SOS I am running this on MS SQL Server. I don't know the exact version of it. I define a week by the calendar from Monday to Sunday and it is not an infinite number. My original data is about the past 3 months. So I want to aggregate my data weekly. I have tried to download the raw data for each case and group it using excel or Python functions, but the tables are too big for me to load. So I'm trying to find a way to aggregate using SQL queries first. I can calculate the total number of people for the whole 3 months by adding COUNT(). But the date column is not taken into account.

Comment: @JiayuZhang Please take a look at the answers and comment if you need further assistance or if something is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of doing it, probably not the best way however. Personally, I feel like this list is not something you'd want to do in SSMS. But rather inside Power BI, Excel or some other software for visualizing data rather than retreiving. Do note that my example below is NOT dynamic in the sense of having more and more weeks. This specifically only works for the 3 weeks specified. Please refer to the documentation to see which date belongs to what week. This is from SSMS v18.7.1

Anyway, here goes:

```
    CREATE TABLE #list (
    timestamp_ID datetime,
    country varchar(255),
    col1 varchar(255),
    col2 varchar(255),
    col3 varchar(255),
)

insert into #list  (timestamp_ID, country, col1, col2, col3)
Values ('2021-01-04 11:00:00', 'US', 'red', 'phone', 'car'),
('2021-01-04 11:00:00', 'US', 'red', 'sms', 'car'),
('2021-01-04 12:00:00', 'US', 'red', 'phone', 'car'),
('2021-01-07 11:00:00', 'UK', 'red', 'phone', 'car'),
('2021-01-08 11:00:00', 'US', 'red', 'phone', 'airplane'),
('2021-01-11 11:00:00', 'UK', 'red', 'sms', 'car'),
('2021-01-11 11:00:00', 'US', 'green', 'phone', 'car'),
('2021-01-12 11:00:00', 'US', 'red', 'phone', 'car'),
('2021-01-16 11:00:00', 'CA', 'red', 'sms', 'car'),
('2021-01-18 11:00:00', 'US', 'blue', 'phone', 'airplane'),
('2021-01-19 11:00:00', 'AU', 'red', 'phone', 'car'),
('2021-01-19 11:00:00', 'AU', 'blue', 'phone', 'train ');


select *, DATEPART(Week,a.timestamp_ID) As 'week'
into #week
from #list a

select a.country, a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, count(*) as 'Amount', a.week 
into #filter
from #week a
group by a.country, a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.week

select a.country, 
a.col1, 
a.col2, 
a.col3, 
case when b.Amount is null then 0 else b.Amount end as 'Week 2', 
case when c.Amount is null then 0 else c.Amount end as 'Week 3', 
case when d.Amount is null then 0 else d.Amount end as 'Week 4'
from #week a
left join #filter b
on a.country=b.country and a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2 and a.col3=b.col3 and b.week = 2
left join #filter c
on a.country=c.country and a.col1=c.col1 and a.col2=c.col2 and a.col3=c.col3 and c.week = 3
left join #filter d
on a.country=d.country and a.col1=d.col1 and a.col2=d.col2 and a.col3=d.col3 and d.week = 4
group by a.country, a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.Amount, c.Amount, d.Amount

drop table #list
drop table #filter
drop table #week
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked in Oracle DB.

```
create table damith.temp_test_01 
(timestamp_ID TIMESTAMP,
Country varchar2(5),
col1 varchar2(8),
col2 varchar2(8),
col3 varchar2(10)
);

insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  ( TIMESTAMP '2021-01-04 11:00:00' ,  'US' ,'red','phone','car' );   
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  (TIMESTAMP  '2021-01-04 11:00:00' ,  'US','red','sms','car'   );
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  ( TIMESTAMP '2021-01-04 12:00:00' ,  'US','red',   'phone','car'   );
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  (TIMESTAMP  '2021-01-07 11:00:00' ,  'UK','red',    'phone','car'   );
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  (TIMESTAMP  '2021-01-08 11:00:00' ,  'US','red',   'phone',   'airplane' )  ; 
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  (TIMESTAMP  '2021-01-11 11:00:00' ,  'UK','red',  'sms',   'car'   );
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  (TIMESTAMP  '2021-01-11 11:00:00' ,  'US','green', 'phone'   ,   'car'   );
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  (TIMESTAMP  '2021-01-12 11:00:00' ,  'US','red',    'phone'   ,   'car'   );
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  (TIMESTAMP  '2021-01-16 11:00:00' ,  'CA','red',   'sms'     ,   'car'   );
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  (TIMESTAMP  '2021-01-18 11:00:00' ,  'US','blue',   'phone'  ,   'airplane' )  ;
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  (TIMESTAMP  '2021-01-19 11:00:00' ,  'AU', 'red',   'phone'   ,   'car'    );
insert into damith.temp_test_01 values  (TIMESTAMP  '2021-01-19 11:00:00' ,  'AU', 'blue',  'phone'    , 'train' );

commit;


  SELECT a.*, nvl(b.number_of_sale,0) as count_at_week_01,nvl(c.number_of_sale,0) as count_at_week_02,nvl(d.number_of_sale,0) 
as count_at_week_03 ,nvl(e.number_of_sale,0) 
as count_at_week_04 FROM 
(SELECT distinct COUNTRY, COL1, COL2, COL3  FROM damith.temp_test_01)a  left outer join 
(SELECT COUNTRY, COL1, COL2, COL3, count(*) as number_of_sale FROM damith.temp_test_01 where   
to_char(timestamp_ID,'W') = 1
group by  COUNTRY, COL1, COL2, COL3
)b on a.COUNTRY= b.COUNTRY and a.COL1= b.COL1 and a.COL2=b.COL2 and a.COL3=b.COL3
left outer join 
(SELECT COUNTRY, COL1, COL2, COL3, count(*) as number_of_sale FROM damith.temp_test_01 where   
to_char(timestamp_ID,'W') = 2
group by  COUNTRY, COL1, COL2, COL3
)c on a.COUNTRY= c.COUNTRY and a.COL1= c.COL1 and a.COL2=c.COL2 and a.COL3=c.COL3
left outer join 
(SELECT COUNTRY, COL1, COL2, COL3, count(*) as number_of_sale FROM damith.temp_test_01 where   
to_char(timestamp_ID,'W') = 3
group by  COUNTRY, COL1, COL2, COL3
)d on a.COUNTRY= d.COUNTRY and a.COL1= d.COL1 and a.COL2=d.COL2 and a.COL3=d.COL3
left outer join 
(SELECT COUNTRY, COL1, COL2, COL3, count(*) as number_of_sale FROM damith.temp_test_01 where   
to_char(timestamp_ID,'W') = 4
group by  COUNTRY, COL1, COL2, COL3
)e on a.COUNTRY= e.COUNTRY and a.COL1= e.COL1 and a.COL2=e.COL2 and a.COL3=e.COL3
;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).